# Is there any limitations of enable barcode for sharepoint 2013 documents or list?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, barcodes

I am enabling Bar-code system in my document library using this is there any limitations of using the enabling Bar-code for the document library or the list in SharePoint 2013

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I know one draw back with the OOTB SharePoint barcode integration that it supports only digits!

Comment: Thanks Hardik.. Is there any limitation?

Comment: Apart from it i don't think that there is any limitation. But you should wait for the answer from other users as well.

Comment: Is below information is helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

> **Barcode** The Barcode policy feature enables you to track physical copies of a document by creating a unique identifier value for a
>   document and inserting a bar code image of that value in the document.
>   By default, bar codes are compliant with the common Code 39 standard
>   (ANSI/AIM BC1-1995, Code 39), and you can plug in other bar code
>   providers by using the policies object model.

The **barcode feature** has been removed in SP 2013 (beta 2) and most likely in the final release. If you plan to implement this feature in SP 2010, be warned that once you upgrade to SP 2013 your feature using barcode will not work. The reason this feature was dropped in SP 2013 is because of low adoption.

For a list of features discontinued in SP 2013 see below article.

[Discontinued features and modified functionality in Microsoft SharePoint 2013](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-Microsoft-SharePoint-2013-bbbb0815-2538-4f1d-b647-1f7f6d508c93?CorrelationId=bf53c2ad-b002-407f-97cd-efcd31c5b890&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Is above information helpful to you? Do you get it or need more information?

Comment: Hello Dinesh, Kindly let me know if my answer did't help you in getting your resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Barcode in SharePoint is part of Information Policy Management, that can be applied to content types or document library.

**Reference Link**: 
[Introduction to information management policies](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-information-management-policies-63a0b501-ba59-44b7-a35c-999f3be057b2)

The limitation, currently it generates the value automatically and doesn't provide a way to accept value from user input or barcode reader.

However you can extend this feature by creating component that will change the barcode value programmatically.

You can follow the steps from [this blog](http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-development/programmatically-changing-a-sharepoint-barcode/)