# Can you change the barcode standard used by SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, barcodes

By default, Sharepoint uses the Code39 barcode standard. Is there any way through the COM or otherwise to change the standard used by sharepoint? I would like to have Code 128B barcodes instead, and can find no documentation online regarding different barcode standards. I'm using SharePoint 2016

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is possible OOTB. Refer to this related thread - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185207/is-there-any-limitations-of-enable-barcode-for-sharepoint-2013-documents-or-list

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Custom Barcode Provider from Planzer for your reference.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace PLA.SP.Core.Barcode {

  /// <summary>
  /// This Class contains the Custom Barcode Provider for Code 128B Codes <br/>  /// </summary>
  public class PlanzerBarcodeGenerator : IBarcodeGenerator {

    private int _barWeight = 2;
    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set the Weight of the Barcode Bar
    /// </summary>
    public int BarWeight {
      get { return _barWeight; }
      set { _barWeight = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws a Code 128B Barcode 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private System.Drawing.Image DrawBarcodeImage(string id) {
      return Code128.MakeBarcodeImage(id, BarWeight, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the document id to create barcode
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="spListItem"></param>
    /// <returns>The document Id of current splistitem</returns>
    private string GetDocumentID(Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem spListItem) {
      if (spListItem.Properties.ContainsKey("_dlc_DocId"))
        return spListItem.Properties["_dlc_DocId"].ToString();
      else
        return "_dlc_DocID_NotFound!";
    }

    #region IBarcodeGenerator

    System.Drawing.Image IBarcodeGenerator.GetBarcodeImage(Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem spListItem, ref string strValue) {
      return DrawBarcodeImage(strValue);
    }

    void IBarcodeGenerator.GetBarcodeValueAndImage(Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem spListItem, out string strValue, out System.Drawing.Image imBarcode) {
      strValue = GetDocumentID(spListItem);
      imBarcode = DrawBarcodeImage(strValue);
    }

    System.Drawing.Image IBarcodeGenerator.GetSampleBarcodeImage(Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite spSite) {
      return DrawBarcodeImage("TEST-12-3");
    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

**For Activating / Deactivating in a Feature**

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides the Provider Manifest to activate it
/// </summary>
const string sBarcodeProviderManifest = "<PolicyResource id=\"PLA.SP.Core.Barcode.PlanzerBarcodeGenerator\" " +
  "featureId=\"Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.Barcode\" " +
  "type=\"Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.Barcode.Generator\" " +
  //"visible=\"true\" " + 
  " xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:server:policy\" >" +
  "<Name>Planzer Code 128B Provider</Name> " +
  "<Description>This is the Planzer 128B Barcode Provider. Default to all Planzer Group Systems</Description> " +
  "<Publisher>planzer group</Publisher> " +
  "<AssemblyName>PLA.SP.Core.RegisterBarcodeProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa3f56284809e565</AssemblyName> " +
  "<ClassName>PLA.SP.Core.Barcode.PlanzerBarcodeGenerator</ClassName>" +
  "</PolicyResource>";


/// <summary>
/// Activates the Barcode 128B for the Planzer Internet Site
/// </summary>
/// <param name="properties"></param>
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
  PolicyResourceCollection.Add(sBarcodeProviderManifest);
}


/// <summary>
/// Deactivates the Barcode 128B feature
/// </summary>
/// <param name="properties"></param>
public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
  PolicyResourceCollection.Delete("PLA.SP.Core.Barcode.PlanzerBarcodeGenerator");
}
```

Reference: [Custom Barcode Provider](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f57e2577-b460-42f0-b7b1-47d3c06cc1f6/sp2010-custom-barcode-provider?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)